# WiFiClientSecure https not working with BluetoothSerial connected on ESP32 Arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32, arduino-esp32, arduino-httpclient

I have a project with an ESP32 chip that I need to program to communicate with a Mobile Phone via Bluetooth and with a server via an HTTPS API.

The problem I have is that when I start the BluetoothSerial the https connection does not connect. I am using the code from the WifiClientSecure example, and added the Bluetooth serial initialization:

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

const char* ssid     = "your-ssid";     // your network SSID (name of wifi network)
const char* password = "your-password"; // your network password

const char*  server = "www.howsmyssl.com";  // Server URL


const char* test_root_ca= \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\n" \
"TzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxKTAnBgNVBAoTIEludGVybmV0IFNlY3VyaXR5IFJlc2Vh\n" \
"cmNoIEdyb3VwMRUwEwYDVQQDEwxJU1JHIFJvb3QgWDEwHhcNMTUwNjA0MTEwNDM4\n" \
"WhcNMzUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WjBPMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJu\n" \
"ZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2ggR3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMTDElTUkcgUm9vdCBY\n" \
"MTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK3oJHP0FDfzm54rVygc\n" \
"h77ct984kIxuPOZXoHj3dcKi/vVqbvYATyjb3miGbESTtrFj/RQSa78f0uoxmyF+\n" \
"0TM8ukj13Xnfs7j/EvEhmkvBioZxaUpmZmyPfjxwv60pIgbz5MDmgK7iS4+3mX6U\n" \
"A5/TR5d8mUgjU+g4rk8Kb4Mu0UlXjIB0ttov0DiNewNwIRt18jA8+o+u3dpjq+sW\n" \
"T8KOEUt+zwvo/7V3LvSye0rgTBIlDHCNAymg4VMk7BPZ7hm/ELNKjD+Jo2FR3qyH\n" \
"B5T0Y3HsLuJvW5iB4YlcNHlsdu87kGJ55tukmi8mxdAQ4Q7e2RCOFvu396j3x+UC\n" \
"B5iPNgiV5+I3lg02dZ77DnKxHZu8A/lJBdiB3QW0KtZB6awBdpUKD9jf1b0SHzUv\n" \
"KBds0pjBqAlkd25HN7rOrFleaJ1/ctaJxQZBKT5ZPt0m9STJEadao0xAH0ahmbWn\n" \
"OlFuhjuefXKnEgV4We0+UXgVCwOPjdAvBbI+e0ocS3MFEvzG6uBQE3xDk3SzynTn\n" \
"jh8BCNAw1FtxNrQHusEwMFxIt4I7mKZ9YIqioymCzLq9gwQbooMDQaHWBfEbwrbw\n" \
"qHyGO0aoSCqI3Haadr8faqU9GY/rOPNk3sgrDQoo//fb4hVC1CLQJ13hef4Y53CI\n" \
"rU7m2Ys6xt0nUW7/vGT1M0NPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNV\n" \
"HRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBR5tFnme7bl5AFzgAiIyBpY9umbbjANBgkq\n" \
"hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAVR9YqbyyqFDQDLHYGmkgJykIrGF1XIpu+ILlaS/V9lZL\n" \
"ubhzEFnTIZd+50xx+7LSYK05qAvqFyFWhfFQDlnrzuBZ6brJFe+GnY+EgPbk6ZGQ\n" \
"3BebYhtF8GaV0nxvwuo77x/Py9auJ/GpsMiu/X1+mvoiBOv/2X/qkSsisRcOj/KK\n" \
"NFtY2PwByVS5uCbMiogziUwthDyC3+6WVwW6LLv3xLfHTjuCvjHIInNzktHCgKQ5\n" \
"ORAzI4JMPJ+GslWYHb4phowim57iaztXOoJwTdwJx4nLCgdNbOhdjsnvzqvHu7Ur\n" \
"TkXWStAmzOVyyghqpZXjFaH3pO3JLF+l+/+sKAIuvtd7u+Nxe5AW0wdeRlN8NwdC\n" \
"jNPElpzVmbUq4JUagEiuTDkHzsxHpFKVK7q4+63SM1N95R1NbdWhscdCb+ZAJzVc\n" \
"oyi3B43njTOQ5yOf+1CceWxG1bQVs5ZufpsMljq4Ui0/1lvh+wjChP4kqKOJ2qxq\n" \
"4RgqsahDYVvTH9w7jXbyLeiNdd8XM2w9U/t7y0Ff/9yi0GE44Za4rF2LN9d11TPA\n" \
"mRGunUHBcnWEvgJBQl9nJEiU0Zsnvgc/ubhPgXRR4Xq37Z0j4r7g1SgEEzwxA57d\n" \
"emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

WiFiClientSecure client;
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);

  SerialBT.begin("BTName"); //Bluetooth device name
  delay(100);
  
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    // wait 1 second for re-trying
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  client.setCACert(test_root_ca);
  //client.setCertificate(test_client_cert); // for client verification
  //client.setPrivateKey(test_client_key);  // for client verification

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (!client.connect(server, 443))
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to server!");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: www.howsmyssl.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    while (client.connected()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
      if (line == "\r") {
        Serial.println("headers received");
        break;
      }
    }
    // if there are incoming bytes available
    // from the server, read them and print them:
    while (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
    }

    client.stop();
  }
}

void loop() {
  // do nothing
}
```

The result after running this code is:

```
Attempting to connect to SSID: StelthF
14:47:18.335 -> ......Connected to StelthF
14:47:24.307 -> 
14:47:24.307 -> Starting connection to server...
14:47:24.841 -> Connection failed!
```

But if I remove `SerialBT.begin("BTName");` I get the following response:

```
14:48:40.379 -> Attempting to connect to SSID: StelthF
14:48:40.519 -> .......Connected to StelthF
14:48:47.502 -> 
14:48:47.502 -> Starting connection to server...
14:48:49.411 -> Connected to server!
14:48:49.620 -> headers received
14:48:49.620 -> {"given_cipher_suites":["TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256","TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"],"ephemeral_keys_supported":true,"session_ticket_supported":true,"tls_compression_supported":false,"unknown_cipher_suite_supported":false,"beast_vuln":false,"able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting":false,"insecure_cipher_suites":{},"tls_version":"TLS 1.2","rating":"Probably Okay"}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to be able to use them both?

Comment: check if you don't run out of memory

Comment: The code does not crash there. If I put is in a loop, it will retry every time and fail. 
I am not sure if this is not proof that it does not run out of memory. But if not, how can I check that?

Comment: Bluetooth and Wifi, both use 2.4 GHz and ESP-32 has only one 2.4GHz ISM band RF module, which is shared. Bluetooth can't receive or transmit data while Wi-Fi is receiving or transmitting data and vice versa. 

[This](https://www.instructables.com/ESP32C3-BLE-to-WiFi-Bridge-BLE-WiFi-Running-Togeth/) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its odd that I can leave answers, but not comments. Some of these Stackoverflow rules seem silly. But, anyway, here is the link I found and Tashfi referenced as well:
https://www.instructables.com/ESP32C3-BLE-to-WiFi-Bridge-BLE-WiFi-Running-Togeth/

Go to step 2, it talks about using Bluetooth with WiFi. They have to share the same radio.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check that and see how it can help. 
I actually manged to fix my problem by finding a workaround :D

Answer (score 0):

So I actually found a solution to my problem.
Unfortunately, I just found a business solution to have them working intermediately.
I am using a hardware switch that when set to one position I am putting the device in a setup mode where I activate Bluetooth and deactivate requests.